# HTML/CSS: Avoid pushdown of DD when displaying DT/DD on same line

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to avoid pushdown of left floating DDs in a DL when containing more text than can it fit in one line.

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/hw2wM/7/
The two first DDs are aligned. However the third one should stay aligned with the first two DDs but instead it is pushed down and takes the entire width...

Features I would like to keep:

- When the DT text is too wide, the DD is gracefully pushed to the right.
- No fixed width
- Stays aligned with an empty DD
- Two DLs displayed side by side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final answer, hope it saves someone time...

Most flexible answer.
http://jsfiddle.net/SeYzF/1/

Thanks @Abody97 for showing the lead.

Main features, on top of Abody97 suggestions:

```
dd:after {content:' '; white-space:pre;}
```

to keep dd to misalign if empty

> div.table {
>       display: table;
>       width: 100%;
>   }
>   div.table > * {
>       display: table-cell;
>   }

to display two DLs side by side

Answer (score 3):

Here's a modified version of your demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/Avnvj/). Two changes:

- `float: left;` in `dd`s changed to `overflow: hidden;`
- Added: `dd:nth-of-type(n+2) { margin-top: 10px; }`

Comment: fantastic! how did you come out with the 10px value for the pseudo elements?

Comment: @gamov It's because the `dd`s are being pushed down twice, once because of their `dt`s, and again because of the `dd` before them.

Comment: @Abody97 One last issue with your method is that the dt/dd pairs get misaligned in case of a empty <dd> (I've updated my answer link)

Comment: @gamov Add `min-height: 20px;` to `dd`. Little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/TpHGX/).

Comment: @Abody97 I noticed a problem with Firefox when doing two floating columns and not specifying widths, the DDs get pushdown, have a look here with FF: http://jsfiddle.net/TpHGX/1/

Comment: @gamov You can set the width to `50%`, demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/suc8w/).

Comment: @Abody97 I didn't want to set width. I worked on an answer, please see  the answer if you are interested. It fixes other problems too so I'm quite happy with it now, thanks again.